# How to turn off http session in Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring-security, httpsession

we use Spring security 3.1.2.RELEASE and we need to switch off HttpSession. Is there any way how to do it? We tryed to use create-session="stateless" attribute of http element, but without any success. Is there any way how to switch of session or at least find where session is created? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *switch off HttpSession* ?

Comment: We need to access our RestWeb services without sessions. Spring security create one new session per request, and we need to switch it of, so result will be 0 session per request.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with [this FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-unwanted-session-creation). You can also find out where the session is created by adding [`<debug />` to your XML configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-web).

Some authentication mechanisms require a session, but others don't. If you use `never` as the `create-session` attribute value then Spring Security won't create a session itself. The `stateless` option should be supported in 3.1, so I'd guess your application is most likely creating the sessions itself. In any case it would help if you clarify what you mean by "without any success" - i.e what actually happens, is there an error?.